# How to get value from JTextField in Jpanel and send it to other JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm writing a code for simple Information manage program. and I have trouble in Java swing Gui. In this code, I plan to JTextField string in Northpanel_center to use in Northpanel_east. But I cannot use it.

```
class Northpanel_Center extends JPanel {
public Northpanel_Center() {
    String[] updown = {"이상", "이하"};
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 4, 4));
    add(new JLabel("   이름   "));
    JTextField name = new JTextField(15);
    add(name);
    add(new JLabel("           "));
    add(new JLabel("팔로워수"));
    JTextField followers = new JTextField(15);
    add(followers);
    JComboBox<String> ud1 = new JComboBox<String>(updown);
    add(ud1);
    add(new JLabel("광고비용"));
    JTextField paid = new JTextField(15);
    add(paid);
    JComboBox<String> ud2 = new JComboBox<String>(updown);
    add(ud2);
    add(new JLabel("광고횟수"));
    JTextField times = new JTextField(15);
    add(times);
    JComboBox<String> ud3 = new JComboBox<String>(updown);
    add(ud3);
    //make a new String with JTextField
    String[] information = new String[4];
    String[] bound = new String[3];
    information[0] = name.getText();
    information[1] = followers.getText();
    information[2] = paid.getText();
    information[3] = times.getText();
    bound[0] = ud1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    bound[1] = ud2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    bound[2] = ud3.getSelectedItem().toString();
    
}
```

And I want to use above String[] in below Jpanel, has Actionlistener.
So when I click the button, call "searching" method which uses above String to argument.

```
class Northpanel_East extends JPanel {
public Northpanel_East() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 2, 2));
    JButton searchBtn = new JButton("조회");
    searchBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Search.searching() // cannot use above String[]
                    
        }
    });
```

to add, searching method like this.

```
public ArrayList<Influencer> searching(String[] information, String[] bound) {
    searchedList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!(information[0].equals(""))) {
        searchByName(information[0]);
    }
    else if (!information[1].equals("")) {
        searchByFollower(Integer.parseInt(information[1]), bound[0]);
    }
    else if (!information[2].equals("")) {
        searchByCost(Integer.parseInt(information[2]), bound[1]);
    }
    else if (!information[3].equals("")) {
        searchByChanceOfAdvertise(Integer.parseInt(information[3]), bound[2]);
    }
    else {
        searchedList = listOfInfluencer;
    }

    return searchedList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with a event driven environment, something happens, then you respond to it.  This means that at some point in the future, you need to access the information.

One way to do this, is to use computed properties, which, when called, calculate their results, rather then having them defined up-front.

```
class Northpanel_Center extends JPanel {

    private JTextField name;
    private JTextField followers;
    private JComboBox<String> ud1;
    private JTextField paid;
    private JComboBox<String> ud2;
    private JTextField times;
    private JComboBox<String> ud3;

    public Northpanel_Center() {
        String[] updown = {"이상", "이하"};
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 4, 4));
        add(new JLabel("   이름   "));
        name = new JTextField(15);
        add(name);
        add(new JLabel("           "));
        add(new JLabel("팔로워수"));
        followers = new JTextField(15);
        add(followers);
        ud1 = new JComboBox<String>(updown);
        add(ud1);
        add(new JLabel("광고비용"));
        paid = new JTextField(15);
        add(paid);
        ud2 = new JComboBox<String>(updown);
        add(ud2);
        add(new JLabel("광고횟수"));
        times = new JTextField(15);
        add(times);
        JComboBox<String> ud3 = new JComboBox<String>(updown);
        add(ud3);
    }

    public String[] getInformation() {
        String[] information = new String[4];
        information[0] = name.getText();
        information[1] = followers.getText();
        information[2] = paid.getText();
        information[3] = times.getText();
        return information;
    }

    public String[] getBound() {
        String[] bound = new String[3];
        bound[0] = ud1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        bound[1] = ud2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        bound[2] = ud3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        return bound;
    }
}
```